# Is it require to use dependency injection in this scenario

Tags: c#, class, dependency-injection

I am having class `ClassA`

`ClassA` having method `Method1`

From another class `ClassB`, I want to access `Method1` method from `ClassA`

Currently, I have used as below format

**ClassB file**

```
public void test()
{
  ClassA obj = new ClassA();
  obj.Method1();
}
```

**My question**

Only one method `test` is using the `ClassA` class reference in `ClassB`. For that if we follow *dependency injection(constructor)*, each time `ClassA` gets initialized in `ClassB` *constructor*. So, I have planned to avoid using DI in this case and used above approach. Is that correct?

Comment: You can opt to register `ClassA` as a singleton. And it's not costly to instantiate a class unless it's doing something heavy in its constructor.

Comment: It entirely depends on what `ClassA` requires and what `Method1` does. If there are no dependencies involved and `Method1` is pure (there are no side effects), it might make more sense to make `ClassA.Method1` static.

Comment: Your question is currently very abstract and broad; this means that any answer will have to be long and discuss all possible scenarios in which DI is or isn't beneficial. I'm afraid this makes this question unsuited for SO. It would be helpful if you make your question and its title very specific. At the very least you should describe how these classes function, which role they play in the application, and what logic they have. But not that even then, DI is never required, which makes your question opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario above, `Method1` should probably be a static method since `ClassA` does not have any constructor parameters, and does not seem to be used more than once.

Dependency injection is meant to solve problems like coupling. For example, if `ClassA` has a bunch of dependencies, `ClassB` would not need to care if `ClassA` is injected as a dependency. I.e.:

```
private ClassA myClassA;
public ClassB(ClassA myClassA){
    this.myClassA = myClassA; // Class B does not need to care how myClassA was constructed!
}
```

Another advantage is that you could replace `ClassA` with a interface, so that `ClassB` does not even have to care what actual implementation it uses. This is often great for testing, since you can replace things like database-access or timers with mocks.

For simple cases where you have a fairly straightforward class, like a list, or a point, there is usually not much reason to use dependency injection.